# Finding non duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, match

I have 2 lists of names:

| ListOfNames1 | ListOfNames2 |
| --- | --- |
| James | James |
| John | John |
| Robert | Robert |
| Michael |  |

I want to make a formula that will detect when a name did not find a match on the other list and output that name, so in this case it would output `Michael`.

There is probably a very simple solution to this but I simply cannot find it.
I tried using stuff such as `UNIQUE()`, `FILTER()` but with no luck.

The demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqN6pB7xRXzWmDe1LPWUmo4HNeuH5PTtf2Ckb1B6dvg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B2:B, A2:A)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution already provided, you can also try this:

```
=FILTER(A2:AA,ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0)))
```

The above formula uses the following functions:

- `MATCH` - in order to return the unique value;
- `ISNA` - for checking whether the match is the error `#N/A`;
- `FILTER` - for returning the desired result;

#### Reference

- [MATCH function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en);
- [ISNA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093293?hl=en);
- [FILTER function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).